# Allow a non-site administrator access to clear-cache through administrator menu, Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, caching, view, panels

I have a site-editor user role with custom permissions. Currently they can access some actions in the admin menu, but they cannot access clear-cache.

I want to expose just that option to the non-administrator (site-editor) user role. I can't find an option that granular in the permissions.

I've found some alternative options, but they involve coding, custom pages, etc. I want a pure drupal GUI option (if any exists). Not: http://drupal.org/node/152983

The reason is that site-editors enter content, but I'm caching panels and views. I need them to be able to clear the cache so they can see the changes they've made.

Answer (score 4):

If you really don't want to create a custom module, there is handbook page on [creating a page to clear your cache](http://drupal.org/node/152983) that includes a [snippet to add to a page using the PHP Input format](http://drupal.org/node/152983#d6) and [a refinement in the comments](http://drupal.org/node/152983#comment-2973618). Keep in mind, using the PHP Input Format is usually discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't take many minutes to create a custom form with a clear-cache button that you can give your editors access to.

The function you need to call to clear the cache is `drupal_flush_all_caches`

I'm not sure how this option differ from a *pure drupal GUI*. They are built the same way after all.

Alternatively, you could write a bit of custom code, to clear your panels/views cache when content is created or edited, which would remove this need.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is an option. I was looking (err hoping) I was overlooking something in the standard GUI / permissions. But cool, yeah I'll probably end up doing something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

use the flush page cache module? 
http://drupal.org/project/flush_page_cache

You can specify what to flush and permit specific roles

Answer (score 1):

If you are using admin_menu, the flush cache ability is given to the 'administer site configuration' permission, which is way bigger than needed. I am thinking of creating a small module that simply does the following:

```
<?php
function flusher_menu_alter($items) {
  $items['admin_menu/flush-cache']['access arguments'] = array('flush cache');
}
function flusher_permission() {
  return array(
    'flush cache' => array(
      'title' => t('Flush the cachce'),
      'description' => t('This allows non admins to flush the cache'),
    );
  );
}
```

How's that sound?

Answer (score 0):

Check the new [CacheFlush](http://drupal.org/project/cacheflush) module for clearing cache with different roles also you can create presets for clearing the cache just you need helping to save time on development process.